# How to loop through ALL content of HashMap

Tags: java, android

How to loop through ALL content of HashMap?
I only get last put

```
   ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

// 0
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("name", "name0");
    map.put("company", "company0");
    list.add(map);
// 1
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("name", "name1");
    map.put("company", "company1");
    list.add(map);


    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        String value = map.get(key);
        Log.w("dd:", "Key = " + key + ", Value = " + value);
    }
```

I only get last put:

```
Key = company, Value = company1
Key = name, Value = name1
```

Comment: You are overwriting your values for the same keys `name` and `company`. Perhaps you want a multi-map with `Set` values?

Answer (score 6):

You have multiple maps in a list.  You need to loop over the list, then loop over the map inside the list.

```
for(HashMap<String, String> curMap : list) {
    //Put your loop over the map here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I treated it as one one map with indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over list first and then over map.

```
for(Map<String, String> myMap: list){
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : myMap.entrySet()){
           Log.w("dd:", "Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " +             
              entry.getValue());
          }
}
```

Comment: Arpit? Do you know Alex Burton?